# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable for ML Model

Tags: python, types, floating-point

How do I avoid getting the error on the highlighted line, it keeps giving me that error on how the float64 type is not iterable. Essentially, I'm trying to calculate the cost for SGD in the first function and then calculate SGD in the second function.

```
def calculate_cost_gradient(W, X_batch, Y_batch):
    # if only one example is passed (eg. in case of SGD)
    if type(Y_batch) == np.float64:
        Y_batch = np.array([Y_batch])
        X_batch = np.array([X_batch])  # gives multidimensional array

    distance = 1 - (Y_batch * np.dot(X_batch, W))
    dw = np.zeros(len(W))

######## Error is here ######## 
    for ind, d in enumerate(distance):
        if max(0, d) == 0:
            di = W
        else:
            di = W - (regularization_strength * Y_batch[ind] * X_batch[ind])
        dw += di

    dw = dw/len(Y_batch)  # average
    return dw


def sgd(features, outputs):
    max_epochs = 5000
    weights = np.zeros(features.shape[1])
    nth = 0
    prev_cost = float("inf")
    cost_threshold = 0.01  # in percent
    # stochastic gradient descent
    for epoch in range(1, max_epochs):
        # shuffle to prevent repeating update cycles
        X, Y = shuffle(features, outputs)
        for ind, x in enumerate(X):
            ascent = calculate_cost_gradient(weights, x, Y[ind])
            weights = weights - (learning_rate * ascent)
        # convergence check on 2^nth epoch
        if epoch == 2 ** nth or epoch == max_epochs - 1:
            cost = compute_cost(weights, features, outputs)
            print("Epoch is:{} and Cost is: {}".format(epoch, cost))
            # stoppage criterion
            if abs(prev_cost - cost) < cost_threshold * prev_cost:
                return weights
            prev_cost = cost
            nth += 1
    return weights
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while implementing SVM from a blog post: https://towardsdatascience.com/svm-implementation-from-scratch-python-2db2fc52e5c2

The solution is just to remove the `if type(Y_batch) == np.float64`.

So that `calculate_cost_gradient` becomes:

```py
def calculate_cost_gradient(W, X_batch, Y_batch):
    ...    
    #if type(Y_batch) == np.float64:
    Y_batch = np.array([Y_batch])
    X_batch = np.array([X_batch])
    distance = 1 - (Y_batch * np.dot(X_batch, W))
    dw = np.zeros(len(W))
    ...
```

It is because `Y_batch` is of type `int64` and it is not converted into NumPy array resulting in the distance being a type of float64. (we can use enumerate only to the collections of items)

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that `distance` is a numpy integer and the code should be:

```
for ind, d in enumerate(range(distance)):
```